# Message section empty in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Analytics Dashboard

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have enabled WSO2 EI to publish data to Analytics profile which resides inside wso2 EI product by default. API Request Count, Message Count , Message Latency are able to seen in dashboard. But I'm unable to find out anything in Messages section of API Page in Dashboard.

Synapse.properties file:
[image: file config]

API Request Count :

[image: API request Count]

API Message Count and Latency:

[image: API Message Count and Latency]

Message Section is Empty:

[image: Message is empty]

I'm unable to do [search operation in Dashboard](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Searching+for+Messages), Shall i know the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try configuring the following in synapse.properties file [1].

```
mediation.flow.statistics.enable=true
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.payloads=true
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.properties=true
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Publishing+ESB+Data+to+Analytics

Comment: Hi @Shanaka Premarathna,
Thanks for your suggestion. I have already modified synapse.properties file as first step and updated config in question as well. i tried global property as well which is mediation.flow.statistics.collect.all=true; none of them are working.